# An integral question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was wondering if someone could possibly tell me
what this integral is or possibly help me figure out
an upper and lower bound for this integral (in terms of $X,Y,\alpha$):

$\int_{X}^{Y} v^{\alpha} (1-v)^{\alpha} dv$, where
$-1< \alpha <0$ and $0< X < Y <1$. $\alpha, X, Y$ are
all real numbers.

Thank you!

Comment: Google "Beta Function". It is very beautiful stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a closed form formula in terms of the [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)

$$\int_{x}^{y} v^{\alpha} (1-v)^{\alpha} dv= -{\frac {{x}^{1+\alpha}{ _2F_1(-\alpha,1+\alpha;\,2+\alpha;\,x)}-{y}^{1+
\alpha}{_2F_1(-\alpha,1+\alpha;\,2+\alpha;\,y)}}{1+\alpha}},$$
where $_2F_1$
$$ \,_2F_1(a,b;c;z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {(a)_n (b)_n \over (c)_n} \, {z^n \over n!}  $$

Comment: @JKasahara: You are welcome. Glad to assist.